# How does it look when others see my github's private repository?

Tags: github, repository

1. Is it possible to check the existence of a private repository and the name of the repository?
2. Is it possible to see the internal code of the private repository?

I visited github of some famous people but there were only public repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `No`. No one can see your `private` repository, as well as the repository name.
You can check it yourself in your browser incognito mode.